# Como comparar dois List<Float> no Junit?

Tags: java, junit

Preciso comparar dois List,e no meu teste usei o

```
assertEquals(lista1, lista2);
Assert.assertTrue(lista1.containsAll(lista2));
```

E o erro que o teste mostra é

> (index:22 size:22) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Ate hoje nunca tinha testado um retorno de List então não sei se estou fazendo certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize os métodos `assertThat` da classe `MatcherAssert` e o método `is` da classe `CoreMatchers`. Exemplo:

```
@Test
public void verificaSeAListaASerTestadaEIgualAEsperada() {
    List<Float> listaASerTestada = Arrays.asList(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    List<Float> listaEsperada = Arrays.asList(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(listaASerTestada, CoreMatchers.is(listaEsperada));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda eu testei,continua dando erro mas vou ver se encontro outra solução.

Comment: @Thiago16Oli Você pode colocar as listas que está tentando testar?

Comment: O problema está no método que retornava a lista eu testei com listas que criei dentro do teste e passou,então vou reescrever de outra maneira meu código achei uma forma um pouco melhor de fazer ele mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.